# How does my iPhone know the original sender for a message sent using GroupMe?

Tags: iphone, sms

Text messages are sent using to the 'group number' but they display in my phone using the person's name of the number in my address book. How is that accomplished?

Something like:

```
Matt Cutts: some stuff about search

     Some stuff I say back to Matt

Larry Paige: some other stuff Larry says

Matt Cutts: LOL
```

Also the navigation view header usually has the name of the person I'm texting with, but in texts sent using groupme, it shows "GroupMe: groupname".

Comment: They sync with your address book.

Comment: No, this is all taking place in the iPhone's own SMS application.

Comment: GroupMe is prefixing the messages with the names. They sync with your address book so they know what you've named a contact in your address book. When they send to you, they prefix it with that name.